# Pages with multiple components

Tags: django, django-templates

When designing a web page that pulls in various bits of information which are handled by various apps(as an example, think of the Facebook home page => news feed handled by a feeds app, comments on those feeds handled by a comments app, a friends list on one side, a ticker on the other), what is the best way to compose these components into a single page.

I have read James Bennett's post about using template tags (http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/07/django-tips-write-better-template-tags/). Is that the standard approach or are there other viable options?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could do includes, but template tags are the cleanest mechanism.

Comment: To do includes, would the "homepage" view need to summon all relevant apps and pass the data to the including template, or is there another way? Is this the mechanism one would include ads from a third party, for example? Thank you!

Comment: Includes use the template directories and loaders. The `app_directories` loader needs the app installed, but `filesystem` doesn't.